# Message: Error creating bean with name 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, bootstrap, spring

Добавил таблицу, вроде настроил контроллер, репозиторий, но выдаёт ошибку. В чём может быть проблема?
Всё на springe, пытаюсь сделать переговорку

Сам контроллер

```
@Controller
public class TableController {
    @Autowired
    private ReservationRepos reservationRepos;

    @GetMapping("/table")
    public String add(String date, Model model) {
        Iterable<Reservation> reservations = reservationRepos.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("reservation", reservations);
        return "table";
    }


    @PostMapping("/table")
    public String add(
            @AuthenticationPrincipal User user,
            Reservation reservation,
            Model model){
        reservation.setAuthor(user);
        Iterable<Reservation> reservations = reservationRepos.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("reservation",reservation);
        return "table";
    }
}
```

Все нужные методы

```
    @Entity
public class Reservation {
    @Id
    private Long id();

    @NotBlank(message = "Please fill the date")
    @JoinColumn(name = "date_reservation")
    private String date;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User author;

    public Reservation() {
    }

    public Reservation(String date, User user) {
       this.author = user;
       this.date=date;
    }

    public User getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(User author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getAuthorName(){
        return author != null ? author.getUsername() : "<none>";
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

И сам репозиторий

```
public interface ReservationRepos extends CrudRepository<Reservation, Long> {

    List<Reservation> findByDate(String date);
}
```

Стэктрэйс

> rg.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to
>   start web server; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to
>   start embedded Tomcat     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   com.nordclan.meetroom.Application.main(Application.java:10)
>   [classes/:na]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
>   [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to
>   start embedded Tomcat     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:125)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.(TomcatWebServer.java:86)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:417)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:176)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    ... 13 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration'
>   defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/SessionRepositoryFilterConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' parameter 1; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.JdbcSessionConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcHttpSessionConfiguration':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'setTransactionManager' parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
>   Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:470)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:226)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:214)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:91)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:79)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:250)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:237)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:54)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5204)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.JdbcSessionConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcHttpSessionConfiguration':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'setTransactionManager' parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
>   Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:668)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   ... 24 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
>   Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   ... 47 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
>   Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:225)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1015)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:339)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:334)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.findEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:121)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.setBeanFactory(JpaTransactionManager.java:312)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1732)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1697)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   ... 56 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:970)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:895)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   ... 70 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException:
>   Schema-validation: missing table [reservation]    at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateTable(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:121)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.validateTables(GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.java:42)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.performValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:89)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:191)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:460)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   ... 77 common frames
>   omitted
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 No identifier specified for entity: com.nordclan.meetroom.domain.Reservation
```

Попробуйте добавить `@Id` для каждой `@Entity` должен быть определен первичный ключ

Comment: Не помогло, но теперь явно другие ошибки

Comment: @AlexRomanov Schema-validation: missing table [reservation] , проверьте что вы правильно указали настройки базы и там есть эта таблица

Comment: добавил в пропити create и да, на удивление всё заработало